# Symfony2 views from .twig to .php

Tags: php, symfony, twig, composer-php

Its way to change defult value from .twig to .php?

Now trying to generate CRUD (with composer), and get views in .twig's, but i need to get it in PHP.

Comment: Why by the way do you want to use php instead of twig ? Twig is really more powerful than php for templating , specially for CRUD design :) you should devellop your needs so we ll be able to help you with twig :)

Comment: In project is using .php, so i need to use php to. Its not are new project. :) So i trying to find are way to build php views from composer.

Answer (score 2):

here is the official documentation on how to achieve this

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']

// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Controller/HelloController.php

// ...
public function indexAction($name)
{
    return $this->render(
        'AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.php',
        array('name' => $name)
    );
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html

Comment: I trying to get "index.html.php" from composer.

Comment: From composer ? could you wrote some code , or give more details ?

Comment: Then we are using this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html it will create controllers and views in bundle. But views is in my_views.twig format, but i need to get my_views.php :)

Comment: Well in that case, you should remove all Twig references ( typically variables with {{ }} or {% %} or {# #} and rename the file from .twig to .php   , don t forget then to update your controller with the right view

Comment: i don t use this bundle , i create manually every controllers / views for projects . But in your case, if you want to use php instead of twig, just rename your twig files to php and remove all twig reference in them and this should work